# Serve resources from a consistent URL

Tags: wordpress, performance, gtmetrix

When I analyze my website on gtmetrix then it shows "Serve resources from a consistent URL" error. My website url is http://yamitpro.co.il/. Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: How much effort have you put into researching that error yourself? I see a number of what seem like useful articles when I Google that error code.

Comment: I have tried many ways but I think it's 2 directories issues.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Your issue is exactly what it says - you have two uploads directories referenced.

You can see this using Browser Development tools under sources:

[image: Your Sources]

Move any old media to your current install and remove any links to your old site.

Comment: Thank for your reply sure I will try this